# Subtract sum of two rows from another row based on condition in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a **dataframe** with three columns- `Col1`, `Col2` and `Col3`

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | a | 10 |
| x | b | 12 |
| x | c | 25 |
| y | a | 13 |
| y | b | 14 |
| y | c | 37 |

I want to update the value of `Col3` for each `c` from `Col2` for each unique `Col1` values by the below logic:

```
c-(a+b)
```

The desired output:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | a | 10 |
| x | b | 12 |
| x | c | 3 |
| y | a | 13 |
| y | b | 14 |
| y | c | 10 |

I would like to know the appropriate operation that I need to do to achieve the desired solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can select the subset of rows where the `Col2` values is either `a` or `b`, then group these rows by `Col1` and transform using `sum` to calculate the transformed sum `a + b` per group, finally subtract the transformed sum from `Col3` where the corresponding `Col2` is `c`

```
m = df['Col2'].isin(['a', 'b'])
s = df['Col3'].where(m).groupby(df['Col1']).transform('sum')
df.loc[df['Col2'].eq('c'), 'Col3'] -= s
```

---

```
  Col1 Col2  Col3
0    x    a  10.0
1    x    b  12.0
2    x    c   3.0
3    y    a  13.0
4    y    b  14.0
5    y    c  10.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be verbose, but a possible way if each group has only one `a`, `b` and `c`.

```py
def subtract(group):
    result = group.loc[df['Col2'] == 'c', 'Col3'].values - (group.loc[df['Col2'] == 'a', 'Col3'].values + group.loc[df['Col2'] == 'b', 'Col3'].values)
    group.loc[df['Col2'] == 'c', 'Col3'] = result
    return group

df_ = df.groupby('Col1').apply(subtract)
```

```
print(df_)

  Col1 Col2  Col3
0    x    a    10
1    x    b    12
2    x    c     3
3    y    a    13
4    y    b    14
5    y    c    10
```

Comment: Thanks!! And as you mentioned, there is a possibility of a fourth value 'd' in Col2 might appear in certain cases. In that case, this solution might not work

Comment: @CrookedNoob This would work. But if you have two `a`, `b` and `c`, it will only consider `c1=c1-(a1+b1)` and `c2=c2-(a2+b2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, If you wanna perform this kind of operation. Why not restructure the data?.
You can use pivot_table ->

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index = 'Col1',columns='Col2', values='Col3')
print(df1)
```

**Output-**

```
Col2   a   b   c
Col1            
x     10  12  25
y     13  14  37
```

Then you can perform the operations that you want easily and after that, if you want data back in its original format you can always use the `melt` function.

```
df1['c'] -= df1['a']+ df1['b']
df1.melt()
```